# How to post data when you have javascript object using multipart/form-data content-type

Tags: reactjs, fetch, httprequest, multipartform-data, form-data

So I have never post a data using `FormData` and `multipart/form-data` as Content-Type in my React project. But now I'm kinda forced by backend to send it this way since we have some images in payload.

The problem is that the whole data is a JS object and can be parsed to JSON, and nothing more. So how can I convert my  JS object into a valid `FormData` that backend would accept it? Everything works without a problem in Postman, but in the app I always get the same error.

Here is some more detail:

The working Postman sample:

[image]

What I expect to be working (but obviously doesn't):

```
const createProd = () =>
  HttpRequest.post('/api/prod', {
    body: {
      Product: {
        title: 'Test Prod',
        shop: null,
        description: "My new ad's description",
        category: { id: '5d8c6aa6fadeaf26b0194667' },
        condition: 'USED'
       }
    });
```

`HttpRequest` is a helper function which uses ES6 `fetch` for requests.

I always get the same error: `"Required request part 'Product' is not present"` with/without `JSON.stringify`.

I even tried to create a sample `FormData` to at least change the error:

```
cont payload = new FormData();
payload.append('Product', {foo: 'bar'});
```

But still same error. I also copied the code which is generated by Postman. But still no chance.

I would be thankful if you share your suggestions or workarounds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this `HttpRequest`? Is it `axios`? Where did you try to put this `JSON.stringify`? Inside `body`? What backend language do you use? Did you try adding headers to your request?

Comment: @k-wasilewski I mentioned that I'm using `fetch` in my React project. I also mentioned that I tried it with/without JSON.stringfy. Anyway, I used `axios` and my problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const formData = new FormData();
const product = { //your product object };
formData.append('product', JSON.stringify(product));

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary="another cool boundary";'
  }
};
axios.post(`/api/ads`, formData, config).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Maybe you should set header.
Try this one. In my case I used Axios. It worked for me in my project.

Comment: Thank you! I guess using axios and not fetch was the key of my problem. Probably there are some ways of using `fetch` but they may not be as straightforward as the way we can do it with axios.